# How to Avoid Exponent Value in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, exponent

I am getting stucked with Exponential Values in jTable in java. Actually I am retrieving values from database and in amount column value is in double. When the jTable is filled with values, amount column values are self converted to Exponential value while the database has normal double values.

I know that how to convert values from exponent to double but this time its in jTable.
Kindly help me out plz asap. Thanks with Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing your own cellRenderer and format your double. Like this

```
jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
        {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, String.format("%s",(double)value), isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            }
        });
```

Comment: First of all thanks Dia and your Code at String.format("%s",(double)value) is showing invalid type provided. However, I made some changing and it's working fine now. Thanks again for prompt reply.

Comment: This should be: return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, (value == null) ? "" : String.format("%f", (Double) value), isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to altering CellRenderers, which could be inappropriate for some kinds of table, you could implement a custom TableModel as a decorator that delegates to the existing TableModel that contains numbers except that it performs on-the-fly conversions from number to strings according to your needs when getValueAt() is called with the appropriate column parameter. You can do the opposite conversions in setValueAt() if the number columns are editable.

Comment: no - it's the task of the renderer to take care of visual representation, the model should contain the objects as-are